# Load more content with ajax in jsf web application

Tags: ajax, jsf

I am building a web application using jsf 2.2 and primefaces 4.0.

On one page which I call experiment view I list results for an experiment saved in a database. Some experiments might have a very long list of experimental results and from each result in the list I build a table of the numeric values for that result, then build a chart (using google charts) for that data. When an experiment contains about 100 results 100 tables and 100 charts need to be built on that page, which takes to long time, so I need to find a solution to how to get around this.

First I tried just rendering all the tables, which doesn't take that much time then incrementally drawing the charts when the user scrolls down. I was not able to make this work in a satisfactory way so I decided to try something else.

My idea now is to use have a command button that when clicked triggers an ajax call and injects about 10 new experimental results bellow the previously rendered. But here I get a bit stuck. I don't know how to achieve this without overwriting the previously rendered list items.

This is how the part of the document rendering the list looks at the moment:

```
<h:form id="assayDataForm" >
<div style="height: 1000px;overflow: scroll !important;" >
    <ui:repeat id="loaded" value="#{exp.loadedAssays}" var="a" >                    
        <div style="width: 900px !important;">
            <p:dataTable style="width:300px !important;  float: left !important;" value="#{a.data}" var="data"  >
                <f:facet name="header" >                                                        
                <h:outputText  value="Data from assay #{exp.expDetail.assayList.indexOf(a) + 1} " />
                </f:facet>
                <p:column headerText="Labels">
                    #{data.labels}
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Value">
                    #{data.value}
                </p:column>                                             
            </p:dataTable>         
        <div id="chart_div#{a.id}" style="width: 600px !important; height: 450px !important; float: left !important;"></div>   
        </div>       
    </ui:repeat>    
</div>
    <h:commandLink rendered="#{exp.totalAssays > exp.loadedAssays.size()}" action="#{exp.loadNextNAssays()}" value="Load more values" >
        <f:ajax render="assayDataForm" execute="@form"  />
    </h:commandLink>        
</h:form>
```

Any hints on how I could modify this so that I don't overwrite previous content?

Comment: Are you familiar with primefaces' [Scrollable Datatable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/scroll.xhtml) and [lazy datamodels](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml)

Comment: Yes, but they are not applicable in this situation. I don't think it is possible to put a chart in the datatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a hidden panel, containing only the latest (let's say) 10 results. and you will have another panel, which is loaded initially and contains the first N records.

each time the ajax request is completed, you will render the "newResultsPanel" and then append it's content to "initialResultsPanel" using javascript/jquery.

```
<div id="initialResultsPanel" ...>
    ...
</div>
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="newResultsPanel" style="display: none;" >
    <ui:repeat id="loaded" value="#{exp.loadedAssays}" var="a" >                    
        ...
    </ui:repeat>    
</h:panelGroup>
<h:commandLink rendered="#{exp.totalAssays > exp.loadedAssays.size()}" action="#{exp.loadNextNAssays()}" value="Load more values" >
    <f:ajax render="newResultsPanel" execute="@form" onevent="eventCompleted" />
</h:commandLink>

<script>
function eventCompleted(data) {
    if (data.status == "success") {
        $('#initialResultsPanel').append($('#newResultsPanel').html());
    }
} 
</script>
```