# Long list of panelGroup from ui:repeat. How to best insert another panelGroup?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2, omnifaces

Basically ui:repeat produces a long list of divs. I would like to use something similar to jquery append() and ajax so that the entire list is not rerendered.

Basically like this:

Customer demand: CTRL + F must work so I cant lazy very well.

1. Render huge list as divs with panelGroup. Pay close attention to generated html because of the huge amount of data...
2. Get websocket call something changed and you need a new element after hugelistForm:div982. Basically jquery append would be great but not sure how to integrate it.

This will cause the List backing the ui:repeat and the view to become disconnected. However the list is updated in the "background" so F5 would make things normal...

I use latest versions of JSF, Primefaces, Omnifaces.

Comment: Why you need ui:repeat ? 
since you are using Primefaces; Is it possible to use Primefaces data-table ?

Comment: @Mohammed: Perhaps because OP don't need to present tabular data? Regardless of the iterator component, OP would still have the same question.

Comment: can you take a look at here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135482/load-more-content-with-ajax-in-jsf-web-application/25139291#25139291

Comment: @tt_emrah: OP needs a working Ctrl+F. So all has to be loaded at once.

Comment: @BalusC: i missed that. you are right, as usual. :)

Comment: @tt_emrah I used something very similar to integrate append() :-)

I needed insertAfter() and it seems to work very well. BalusC is right - I can't lazy load. However I can still make sure new rows are sneaked in this way.

I use a single o:commandScript to pull in new data to append. It works very well.

Comment: @MohammadAlkhateeb First I try with html, then jsf, then omnifaces, then tiny js/jquery stuff.

If I still need primefaces after that I use it :-)

Comment: @KarlKildén : then, as a workaround, can you override ctrl+f keyboard event on page, and take the search input yourself?